# pe:imageRotateAndResize not working with p:graphicImage cache=false

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, jsf-2.2, primefaces-extensions

I am using primefaces extensions to zoom and rotate images:

```
<p:graphicImage id="imageViewerId" value="#{contentBL.inlineContent}" cache="false" />
<pe:imageRotateAndResize id="rotateAndResizeImageId" for="imageViewerId" widgetVar="rotateAndResizeVar" />

<p:commandButton title="Rotate Left" icon="fa fa-mail-reply"
                            onclick="PF('rotateAndResizeVar').rotateLeft(90); adjustContentViewerSize(); return false;" />
<p:commandButton icon="fa fa-mail-forward" title="Rotate Right"
                            onclick="PF('rotateAndResizeVar').rotateRight(90); adjustContentViewerSize(); return false;" />
<p:commandButton icon="fa fa-plus-circle" title="Scale +"
                            onclick="PF('rotateAndResizeVar').scale(1.1); adjustContentViewerSize(); return false;" />
<p:commandButton icon="fa fa-minus-circle" title="Scale -"
                            onclick="PF('rotateAndResizeVar').scale(0.9); adjustContentViewerSize(); return false;" />
```

Unfortunately this only works if attribute `cache` of `p:graphicImage` is `true`. If set to `false`, nothing happens if the rotate or zoom buttons are clicked. `#{contentBL.inlineContent}` delivers `StreamedContent`. Is there a way to get this working without caching the images? I am using primefaces 5.3.0 and primefaces extensions 4.0.0 and mojarra 2.2.12.

Comment: Correct. The images shall not be cached. But `pe:imageRotateAndResize` is not working then.

Comment: Ahhh sorry, double negation. Will remove my comment!

Answer (score 0):

Made the url unique with `f:param` as workaround:

```
<p:graphicImage id="imageViewerId" value="#{contentBL.inlineContent}" cache="true">             
    <f:param name="customid" value="#{contentBL.generateUuid()}" />
</p:graphicImage>
```

Comment: Sorry but I do not have access to the code anymore.